# Twitter Bootstrap: Drop down menu disappears in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The navbar that I have managed to create is working just fine. However, when I collapse the navbar by re-sizing the window it disappears as I try to open the menu in that view.
Why is the drop-down menu disappearing in mobile view. What am I doing wrong?

HTML code:

```
 <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Kirori Mal College</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">  

       <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true">Why Recruit?  <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Why Recruit?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Demographics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Faculty</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Academics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alumni</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
 <!-- End of nav bar tabs -->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Link to [Website](http://avenueskmc.github.io/New/index.html) and 
Link to [CSS file](http://avenueskmc.github.io/New/css/creative.css).

Comment: The site links and CSS link are the same.

Comment: did you referred the bootstrap js file in your html file?

Comment: @KhairulIslam It didn't work. The links provided are working now. Please check them.

Comment: I have fixed it. It seems I had custom js that closes responsive menu when an item is clicked. Thanks anyway